# Choosing spatial reference for GPS data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, gps

We received GPS data from the vendor.
I want using ArcGIS software to create XY event table and create a point feature class.

- What the spatial reference would be for the GPS data?
- Is it something I should ask the vendor about?
- Is it from the GPS device?

Comment: You should ask your vendor. It sounds as if you are receiving an esri shapefile, and the output reference can be modified on most devices when using esri output.

Answer (score 4):

GPS devices normally use WGS 84 as the reference system. As far as my experience goes all GPS devices support this format.So you don't have to worry, your device will also support WGS 84.

Source:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System

Answer (score 2):

@DotPi is correct that GPS devices natively use WGS 84. However, if any type of real-time or post-processing is done to improve the data's accuracy, the coordinate reference system will be the same as the control network that is used. Thus, if in the US, the CORS network is used, the coordinate reference system would be NAD 83 (2011).

The provider could also have transformed or projected the data after the processing. Ask them.